# Best tool to Install Linux onto USB using Windows?

Tags: 14.04, live-usb, persistence, portable

What is the best tool to use to create a live USB with persistant data? I have tried Universal USB Installer one but within half an hour of using booting into it if I restart something happens either I cant login or everything is buggy or it will just keep booting.

Comment: You may also be interested in how to fully install Ubuntu on an USB-key: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use LiLi http://www.linuxliveusb.com, an easy-to-use tool. 
There's even the portable version and some usually future, like virtual box inside the usb to launch a O.S. from Windows, or the persistence mode, to have a truely OS on your usb key!

Answer (score 1):

For me I always use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/) it's fast and good one

Comment: One time i keeped Unetbootin on my Ubuntu system to try out Linux distros and it corrupted the Ubuntu font. It also failed to do a lot of stuff.

Comment: @Star OS  but he wants to use it on windows !!

Comment: Oh, use Unetbootin like you want then.

Comment: @Maraboc, is it known whether UNetbootin performs better when used in a Windows environment vs Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Emily for me i am using Unetbootin only on Windows, so i can't give you an appropriate answer :(